# SharePoint 2013 Community - How are they not integrated into the Newsfeed?

Tags: 2013, social, community

Yes, Yammer will replace social stuff with SharePoint Online. I still want to get the Communities to work the way they are supposed to work and right now they seem buggy / not useful.

Suppose we have a community "Marketing". And we have "Katie" and "Jordan" joined the community (and follow it).

Katie creates a new discussion entry "Test Entry". On Katies Newsfeed the entry appears "Katie posted "Test Entry" in "Marketing". That's great. Katy just received a notification that she posted herself. Hooray.

See this image for an example (Robin created a new discussion entry, she gets a newsfeed entry - nobody else does):
[image]

Jordan on the other hand doesn't see a thing in the Newsfeed. She doesn't see that there is activity in the Community, so why should she bother checking it for new discussion entries?

I have checked this behavior with Office 365 as well as On-Premise SharePoint.

Secondly: Communities don't have the Newsfeed enabled by default. Why would one only to have a discussion board? A "community" is more than just discussions. It's files, newsfeed and lively communication, not always discussions. Enabling the Newsfeed feature works though.

Please tell me that the Community --> Newsfeed integration is still buggy and this is not the desired outcome, that every community member sees his/her own posts in his/her own Newsfeed. (Yes, I could tag people in the posts "@Katie" and they will receive notifications - this is not the intent)

Answer (score 2):

We used SharePoint blogs in the past and faced a similar problem: Although someone follows the blog website this does not mean that this person will get any newsfeed updates (for instance, when someone creates a new blog post). In SharePoint you only get newsfeed updates when you follow the person who creates the blog post. This does not make sense sometimes (because you would have to follow all people in your organization because everyone could potentially be an author of a corporate blog post for instance). 
BTW: You get also status updates when you follow certain documents or hashtags. (but this is not the topic here) Following a site in SharePoint means only that you get information from the sitefeeds (newsfeed channel in the specific sites) aggregated to the newsfeed channel in the MySite.

With communities it’s pretty similar or even worse because you can’t even set up an old-fashioned alert as easy as when working with the blog template.
I suppose that the newsfeed functionality is missing (Communities and Blogs) on the homepage of the site because communities and blogs are communication means compelling with the embedded newsfeed.