# Sharepoint Online - Followed Site activity in Newsfeed

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, discussion-board, newsfeed, community

We are using O365/Sharepoint Online 2013 Plan 1.

I've been trying to search the internet for information about the issue but cannot find anything recent. So my problem/question is that why there are no notifications in user's Newsfeed when someone creates a new thread/topic in a community site that the user is following? I found one good, detailed question about this same problem here:

[SharePoint 2013 Community - How are they not integrated into the Newsfeed?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70470/sharepoint-2013-community-how-are-they-not-integrated-into-the-newsfeed)

But there are no answers yet and it's an old question already. Thanks for any help/information regarding this problem! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, it's not possible to get notifications unless you are mentioned or replied to. All Newsfeed settings can be found at  About Me > Edit > ... > Newsfeed settings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Reference: [Change your newsfeed settings](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/office365-sharepoint-online-enterprise-help/change-your-newsfeed-settings-HA102926000.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Still I don't mean the email notifications though. I'm talking about the notification entries in personal newsfeeds of the users. Somehow it seems that it is by design, which is a quite weird. I think it should be clear as day that if a user follows a community site and someone writes a new post there, he/she should get an entry of it in his/her personal newsfeed. I think we just need to accept it as one of the MS Design Mysteries! ;-)

Comment: @Tenttu True that! :-)